# initialize dense tensorflow layer with pretrained weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to initialize the weights and biases of `tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense` with pretrained weights and biases. I've tried 2 methods, first

```
        dims = [960,480,200,75,25]
        dense_params['weights'] = (weights['w1'], biases['b1']) # [960, 480], 960
        dense2_params['weights'] = (weights['w2'], biases['b2']) # [480, 200], 480
        dense3_params['weights'] = (weights['w3'], biases['b3']) # [200, 75], 200
        dense4_params['weights'] = (weights['w4'], biases['b4']) # [75, 25], 75
    
        # define and initialize MLP model
        mlp = Sequential([
            Dense(dims[1], input_shape=(dims[0],), # 480
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(mlp_l2),
                  kernel_initializer=weights['w1'],
                  bias_initializer=biases['b1']),
            Activation('sigmoid'),
            Dense(dims[2], # 200
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(mlp_l2),
                  kernel_initializer=weights['w2'],
                  bias_initializer=biases['b2']),
            Activation('sigmoid'),
            Dense(dims[3], # 75
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(mlp_l2),
                  kernel_initializer=weights['w3'],
                  bias_initializer=biases['b3']),
            Activation('sigmoid'),
            Dense(dims[4], # 25
                  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(mlp_l2),
                  kernel_initializer=weights['w4'],
                  bias_initializer=biases['b4']),
            Activation('sigmoid'),
            Dense(4, kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=5555)),
            Activation('softmax'),
        ])
        mlp.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=lr),
                    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

which gives the exception

```
ValueError: Could not interpret initializer identifier: tf.Tensor(
[[-0.2785529   0.4547253   0.893165   ... -0.73468804 -0.9307138
   0.52965516]
 [-0.31190312  0.5024654   0.35986277 ... -0.61041874 -0.39063498
  -0.8553045 ]
 [ 0.8878816  -0.75287884 -0.63842094 ... -0.38421196 -0.16647834
  -0.26172128]
 ...
```

The second method I've tried is

```
    dims = [960,480,200,75,25]
    dense_params['weights'] = (weights['w1'], biases['b1']) # [960, 480], 960
    dense2_params['weights'] = (weights['w2'], biases['b2']) # [480, 200], 480
    dense3_params['weights'] = (weights['w3'], biases['b3']) # [200, 75], 200
    dense4_params['weights'] = (weights['w4'], biases['b4']) # [75, 25], 75
    mlp = Sequential([
    Dense(dims[1], input_shape=(dims[0],), # 480
          kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(mlp_l2),
          kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=3333),
          **dense_params),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
    Dense(dims[2], # 200
          kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(mlp_l2),
          kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=4444),
          **dense2_params),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
    Dense(dims[3], # 75
          kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(mlp_l2),
          kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=4444),
          **dense3_params),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
    Dense(dims[4], # 25
          kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(mlp_l2),
          kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=4444),
          **dense4_params),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
    Dense(4, kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=5555)),
    Activation('softmax'),
])
mlp.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=lr),
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

which gives `ValueError: Layer weight shape (480,) not compatible with provided weight shape (960, 1)`

I've also tried the last method without `input_shape` which gives the error
`ValueError: Layer weight shape (200,) not compatible with provided weight shape (480, 1)`

The weights are 2D Tensors with dimensions shown in the comments, the biases are 1D tensors also shown in the comments.  How do I initialize weights and biases?